# how to use ionic script in angular project

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I need to know how to implement the below script in my angular index.html file

`<script src='node_modules/@ionic/core/dist/ionic.js'></script>`

It is throwing as above URL is not found even though I have installed @ionic/core. Can someone help me with this

i tried to include that script in angular index.html file but it not working

Thanks in advance

Regular
    
    
      Pinterest